# How to set jvm parameters for server according to the memory size

Tags: java, jvm

Our server has report an error for OutOfMemoryError, the server has a 32g memory, while we check the jvm parameters, the jvm parameters is as below:

```
-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -Xmn768m -XX:PermSize=128m -Xss256k
```

Of course, it's too small, then, I wanna what is the best practice for setting the jvm parameters

Comment: Which version? java >=8 has not PermSize.

Comment: There is no simple answer. very big heap on machines like Your generate GG freeze etc ... It depends ...

Comment: @Jacek Cz it's jdk7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is as follow:

1. give all the memory available in your server to your application
2. Stress test it while monitoring your memory (Used memory + GC pause)
3. Lower the memory allocated to your application and stress test again
4. repeat step 2 and 3 until OutOfMemoryError appear

Finaly choose the RAM value without OutOfMemoryError and with the less induced GC pause

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your Application server. For example: 
For tomcat you need to modify the CATALINA_OPTS of tomcat.

```
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "run" or "debug" command is executed.
#                   Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
#                   only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.

#   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when any command
#                   is executed.
#                   Include here and not in CATALINA_OPTS all options, that
#                   should be used by Tomcat and also by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Most options should go into CATALINA_OPTS.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some "dirty" debugging, I suggest to use

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2G -Xms1G -Xcheck:jni"
```

These settings will be taken by each `JVM` that can "see" this variable.

Sometimes, it's quickest way to find best settings for you app.

Then, put preferred settings in proper place (depending on server).